# haskell GHC error

Tags: haskell, ghc

How do I resolve this warning? (I never got it before, but did a new install of a package, and it seems to have now given errors on a previous working package.)

```
  Warning: In the use of `isEmptyChan'
             (imported from Control.Concurrent, but defined in Control.Concurrent.Chan):
             Deprecated: "if you need this operation, use Control.Concurrent.STM.TChan instead.  See http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4154 for details"
```

Comment: Did you read the ticket that it links to?

Comment: Oh come *on*. The answer is *right there in the warning*. What do you expect anyone else to tell you?

Comment: Pretty harsh! The bug (warning) came from code from cabal install, not my code. It was in FRP examples. I certainly don't want to go into FRP code and try to re-write it. I suppose that the message is that there are isEmptyChan functions in both packages, and just the imports in the using code need to change which is used; but I am not familiar with either package, not the FRP source that uses them, nor want to start having to rewrite them.

Comment: @guthrie: Well... the warning is still pretty self-explanatory, really, and the (nicely helpful) answer you got basically quoted Wikipedia and rephrased the warning message. I have to say -6 seems a bit excessive though, I've seen far worse questions at higher scores. So please don't take that (or my earlier annoyance) too personally. :[

Comment: @camccann - Well, as noted Since it comes from code that I do not own and don't want to have to re-write, I was looking to see if anyone who owns that code or uses it knew if there was a solution for clients of the code, not maintainers. I guess not.

Comment: @guthrie: Might have been better off asking that more explicitly then... :[ And yeah, the answer there is "either ignore the warning, or contact the maintainer". It's only a warning, anyway.

Comment: If it is a warning, can't you simply ignore it?

Comment: @camccann - Yes, good points. I thought there might be some easy known "external" solution. Anyway, after several other rebuilds and installs, it has now dissapeared - sunspots? :-)

Answer (score 3):

As the warning indicates, Control.Concurrent.Chan is now [deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation):

`...deprecation is a status applied to software features to indicate that they should be avoided, typically because they have been superseded.`

And to avoid the warning, simply follow the instructions and use the [Control.Concurrent.STM.TChan](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/2.1.1.2/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-STM-TChan.html) instead.

Of course, since it is simply a warning, you could ignore it; but that's definitely not the best choice. The cause of this should be the recent update.

It's perfectly understandable that terminology might be confusing; in that case Google and Wikipedia could be your best friends:)

Comment: Well, he may be getting the warning while installing something from Hackage, rather than from his own code. In that case another option is "bug the maintainer about it".

Comment: @camccann: Good point. I wish I could bug other people more often, though:)